# Interpolate NaN values over a DataFrame as a ring

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to interpolate the `NaN` values over a `Dataframe` but I want that interpolation to get the first values of the `DataFrame` in case the `NaN` value is the last value. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"a": [1,2,3], "b":[1,2,np.nan]})
```

So the DataFrame is:

```
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  NaN
```

But when I interpolate the nan values like:

```
df.interpolate(method="linear", inplace=True)
```

I got:

```
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  2.0
```

The interpolation doesn't use the first value to do it. My desired output wold be to fill in with the value of 1.5 because of that circular interpolation.

Comment: try this `df.fillna(1.5,inplace=True)`

Comment: Really @AmazingThingsAroundYou ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is add first row, interpolate and remove last row:

```
df = df.append(df.iloc[0]).interpolate(method="linear").iloc[:-1]
print (df)
     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  1.5
```

EDIT:

More general solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b":[np.nan,1,2,np.nan]})

df = pd.concat([df] * 3).interpolate(method="linear").iloc[len(df):-len(df)]

print (df)
   a         b
0  1  1.333333
1  2  1.000000
2  3  2.000000
3  4  1.666667
```

Or if need working only with last non missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"a": [1,2,3,4], "b":[np.nan,1,2,np.nan]})

df1 = df.ffill().iloc[[-1]]
df2 = df.bfill().iloc[[0]]
df = pd.concat([df1, df, df2]).interpolate(method="linear").iloc[1:-1]

print (df)
   a    b
0  1  1.5
1  2  1.0
2  3  2.0
3  4  1.5
```

Comment: This is a toy example. Imagine that I got NaN's at the first and last element and I want to interpolate with a ring using two data in the middle of them.

Comment: @Angelo Then I gues you should give that type of sample in the question for better understanding.